# Using variable value as 'name identifier' javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function in javascript that adds rows to an HTML table when called.
In the row, one of the additions is a radio checkbox, which only allows one box to be checked for every radio under the same 'name'.
For this reason, each time the function is called to add a row, the 'name' attribute must change.

```
var namedata = "daynight" + rowCount;
//irrelevant intermediary code. Creates the new row and cell. Then:
newcell.innerHTML = '<input type="radio" name=namedata value="am">';
//and
newcell.innerHTML = '<input type="radio" name=namedata value="pm" checked>';
```

I tried this (and a few other variations) for the 'name' option, but every time I click the button to add the row, every addition goes under the same name (so only one box can be checked in all newly created rows, instead of each row individually).

`namedata` will contain the desired name plus the row number, insuring each 'name' will be different.

How do I get the 'name' attribute of 'input' to receive the value of 'namedata'? And would this fix my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var namedata = "daynight" + rowCount;

newcell.innerHTML = '<input type="radio" name="' + namedata + '" value="pm" checked>';
```

Comment: Perfect! What exactly is it doing? How does the "' + namedata + '" register the value of namedata? I haven't seen that notation before

Comment: Have a look at the [javascript operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp). What you're looking for is to concatenate multiple strings together (One of them being a variable, just like you did in `namedata`).

Comment: right, but there is nothing before the first plus or after the second plus. Is it concatenating a blank space alongside the value of namedata?

Comment: What are you talking about? It's concatenating the string `'<input type="radio" name="'`, the variable `namedata`, and the string `'" value="pm" checked>'` (And then assigning that to the `innerHTML` property of `newcell`)

Comment: Oh got it! I was looking at it wrong.  I saw it as : `name=" ' + namedata + ' "`, where the single quotes denoted a statement within the quotes.  Thanks for clarification.